# Performing spatial searches in nHibernate

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, spatial

I want to use spatial searches in nHibernate v3.3.1.4000 but `nHibernate.Spatial` does not support the latest version of nHibernate. I found out that it's in the form of `HashFoo.Nhib.Spatial`. What can I do to perform spatial searches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate Spatial is not longer maintained (or so it seems). Fortunately there have been some attempts by the community to create github copies from the sourceforge data and keep it up to date with the latest NH revisions.

Although some are less successful than others you can try, for instance, the following project for compatibility with 3.3.1.4000:

https://github.com/suryapratap/Nhibernate.Spatial